# Php Post name in Email Body

Tags: php, email

Im new to php, i have a working contact form, but I would like to add the senders name into the body of the email I receive, this is what I have tried -

```
 <?php 
 $to = "joedunlopburns@gmail.com"; 
 $subject = "The Lantern Contact"; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['name']; 
 $email = $_REQUEST['email']; 
 $message = "Message from $name\n$message";
 $headers = "From: $email"; 
 $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ; 
 ?>
```

sorry if I'm being stupid!

Edit- Form added

```
<form id="contactform" method="POST" action="php/contact.php">
<input class="equal" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Name"><br/><br/>
<input class="equal" type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Email Address"><br/><br/>
<input class="hide" type="email" name="fake">
<textarea class="equaltall" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br/><br/>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: a) Why $message *and* $body? b) If you have the $name, then why don't you do anything with it?

Comment: I use the name to say, Thank you $name, We will reply soon. What i would like is for $name to be printed in the message so I get the senders Name and not just their email address, thanks

Comment: Change `$body = $_POST ["$name"] ;` to `$body = $_POST["name"];` for one thing.

Comment: Yet, this `mail($to, $subject, $message, $body, $headers)` is invalid. You can only have one message body.

Comment: Here: `$message = "Message from $name\n$message";` and get rid of `$body = $_POST["$name"];` and change `($to, $subject, $message, $body, $headers)` to `($to, $subject, $message, $headers)` that oughta kick 'er into high gear ;-)

Comment: Thank you Fred, much appreciated, its much closer, only now the message itself does not show, just the Message from "x", any idea's?

Comment: Might be your form's element's not named, or has a typo. Include the form in your question so I can look at it.

Comment: I tested your code, got back `Message from Fred
asdfasfd` along with what I suggested above.

Comment: Ok man thank you, I will keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use either $_POST and $_GET than $_REQUEST, and you are using $_POST for the body line, so I assume your data are sent using post.

When you receive any user input, you definitely have to test it. You can use [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) to do that.

```
 <?php
     $to = 'me@gmail.com'; 
     $subject = 'Contact'; 
     $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
     $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 
     $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
     $body = $name; // why not use name in the following code?
     $headers = "From: $email"; 
     $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $body, $headers) ; 
 ?>
```

I would also advise not to use the given email address as sender, because the message could then be considered as a spam, coming from a non related smtp server...